# Machine learning model accuracy

Tags: machine-learning

A machine learning model gets an accuracy of 90% on a dataset with 90% positive class and 10% negative class. Can we conclude that the model is a 
       good classifier of the data?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think its pretty accurate. But it was an T/F question in my homework.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an classification problem to choose whether the sample is in the positive class or not, the classifier of accuracy 90% is not quite good. Consider the trivial classifier, declaring any sample to be positive, which provides 90% accuracy.

I think that **imbalanced dataset** is the appropriate keyword.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** The question behind the question is this:

> Does there exist a completely useless classifier that still acheives a $90\%$ accuracy?

If there is such a classifier, then we can't conclude from the given information that our classifier is any good. If there is no such classifier, then our classifier must at least be doing *something* right.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an example that we have a dataset that which has 90 examples of class A(say positive class) and 10 examples of class B(say negative class). Then we can make a "dumb" model that always say Class A, as prediction on training data, then we get the accuracy of 90% on training data which is naive and "dumb" prediction, thus accuracy of 90% in a data set containing 90% class A is not that good.
So our model is not doing a great thing, and hence model is not a good classifier.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A good measurement for this is the confusion matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

If you have to test to predict a rare disease with people and only 1% has this disease. If a classifier would predict everyone NOT to have the disease, it would be 99% accurate. A common misunderstanding in statistics.